# JQuery Datepicker display date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

I have a working version of jQuery datepicker which is defaulted to today's date and display in below format,

[image]

I needed to format the display date like below. How can I do it?

[image]

Here is the JS code

```
viewDate = function () {
            $('#Date').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate:"-5y",
                maxDate: 'today',
                onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
                    doSomething(selected);
                }
            }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
        },
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try setting date format like this: `dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"` and add property `monthNames: ['January', 'February'...]`

Comment: It's right in [the docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat). Why haven't you tried changing the value for `dateFormat`?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic The `-` should be spaces.